# How to add two panels and resize them when frame change sizes?

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel, layout-manager

I have three classes. `GameFrame` extends `JFrame`, `GamePanel` & `InfoPanel` extend `JPanel`.
I am looking for the best solution how to add those two panels to frame like on the picture:

[image]

The initial size of `GamePanel` must be (800x800). I would like that when changing the size of the window, both panels also change the size to fit the window. How to do it?

Comment: *"`GameFrame` extends `JFrame`, `GamePanel` & `InfoPanel` extend `JPanel`."* I bet that there is no need to extend `JFrame`, and possibly that the `InfoPanel` should not extend `JPanel`. Is `GamePanel` custom painted? That's probably the only good case for extending a container. Put `InfoPanel` in the `PAGE_START` & `GamePanel` in the `CENTER` of a `BorderLayout`. Both panels will be stretched to the available width. The `GamePanel` will get the extra height.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you need to set the layout of `GameFrame` to [Border Layout](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/border.html) and add `InfoPanel` to the `NORTH` of `GameFrame` and `GamePanel` to the `CENTER`. `BorderLayout` will automatically resize its components to match the size of the `JFrame`.

Comment: Ok thanks. And how can i get the current size of my GamePanel?

Comment: you should be able to call `gamePanel.getSize()`

Comment: Yeah it works :D But can you explain me why when i call frame.getWidth() it returns 734, but when I call gamePanel.getWidth() it returns 718? I am setting gamePanel size 718. But i don't understand why frame has 734.

Comment: If you call `setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.RED))` on your JPanels, you should be able to see the exact border of each panel and see why the widths display as they do compared to the JFrame.

Comment: Great. Thank You :)

Comment: Would you mind accepting the solution, glad I could help!